# Xamarin.Android Java Bindings java 'is not abstract and does not override' error

Tags: java, binding, xamarin.android

I've got a Xamarin.Android Java Binding project that compiles, but when I reference the .dll to my Xamarin.Android project, and build that, I get an error that surprisingly, if I click on it, I go through to Java code, not the autogenerated C# code:

```
RedactedImplementor.java(8,8): Error JAVAC0000:  error: RedactedImplementor is not abstract and does not override abstract method onNewValue(RedactedValue) in RedactedListener
public class RedactedListenerImplementor
 (JAVAC0000) (MyXamarinAndroidProjectName) javac
```

How do I approach an issue like this?

Can I resolve this using the Xamarin.Android Java Binding library, or is it a fundamental problem where the Java needs to be edited.

In the case that it is the latter, have I read it correctly that the fact  that the error says `and does not override abstract method onNewValue(RedactedValue)` means that this is really problematic in that I haven't a clue what should go in the override (however editing the java by making the class abstract should resolve that)?

Kind regards,

Anthony